# Unexpected result when masking alpha values of QImage using NumPy

Tags: python, pyside2, qimage

I need to use a numpy array to mask the alpha values on a QImage.

I've read different approaches but none of them were very efficient.

I also tried using `for` loops on a list, to test if it was a numpy bug but I got the same results. I don't understand where I'm making a mistake.

```py
from PySide2.QtGui import QImage
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
import numpy as np
import qimage2ndarray as q2np

contour = QImage()
contour.load("contour.png")
contour.convertTo(QImage.Format_Grayscale8)

np_cont = q2np.byte_view(contour)
np_cont = np_cont.reshape(np_cont.shape[:-1])

red = QImage(contour.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
red.fill(Qt.red)

alpha = q2np.alpha_view(red)
alpha *= np_cont.astype(np.bool)

red.save("result.png")
```

Input contour:

[image: contour.png]

Resulting image from masking:

[image: result.png]

The desired result should be similar to the input, note that besides the additional curves the lines are thicker.

I'm not sure where the program is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n Python, all numbers are considered "True" except for the 0 that is "False", so when you convert a Boolean to "alpha" if a pixel of 10 is a black color in the gray scale, it becomes 1 that is white in the boolean scale so that it generates the change, so to convert to boolean using astype(np.bool) is not the best option but to establish a more suitable threshold, for example 127:

```py
from PySide2.QtGui import QImage
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
import numpy as np
import qimage2ndarray as q2np

contour = QImage()
contour.load("contour.png")
contour.convertTo(QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
np_cont = q2np.byte_view(contour)
np_cont = np_cont.reshape(np_cont.shape[:-1])
red = QImage(contour.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
red.fill(Qt.red)

alpha = q2np.alpha_view(red)
alpha *= np_cont > 127  # .astype(np.bool)
red.save("result.png")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works for this case, sometimes the pixel might be between 0 and 1, so I will make a function to binarize the image. But I'm not sure why a few pixels are not exactly zero, is it because of a rounding behavior of numpy?

Comment: @JoOkuma The problem in itself is how you generate the "contour.png" since it has some elements around "10" that are not visible initially but when binarizing with your method they become visible.